# How to insert icons in a message in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, markdown

Can you help me adjust the text that is being displayed in the shiny app and also insert two icons, as per the attached image?. Regarding the text, I could increase the font a little, and regarding the icons: look at the image that has two icons, one for the message and other for the contact phone number. I would like, if possible, those same or similar icons.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("Contact",
                             icon = icon("support"),
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                               ),
                               wellPanel(
                                 includeMarkdown("README.md")
                                 
                               )
                             )
                    )))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**README.md**

```
# **CONTACT**

Feel free to contact us through any of our communication channels.

Any comments, questions or suggestions are most welcome.

Channels:

teste@gmail.com.

(55) 9999-9999
```

**How it turned out:**

[image]

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust in `README.md`

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></button> teste@gmail.com.

<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i> (55) 9999-9999
```

[image]